# Unique configuration per vhost for Micro

Tags: node.js, http, process, microservices

I have a few Zeit [micro](https://github.com/zeit/micro) services. This setup is a RESTful API for multiple frontends/domains/clients

I need to, in my configs that are spread throughout the apps, differentiate between these clients. I can, in my handlers, setup a `process.env.CLIENT_ID` for example that I can use in my config handler to know which config to load. However this would mean launching a new http/micro process for each requesting domain (or whatever method I use - info such as client id will prob come in a header) in order to maintain the `process.env.CLIENT_ID` throughout the request and not have it overwritten by another simultaneous request from another client.

So I have to have each microservice check the client ID, determine if it has already launched a process for that client and use that else launch a new one.

This seems messy but not sure how else to handle things. Passing the client id around with code calls (i.e. `getConfg(client, key)` is not practical in my situation and I would like to avoid that.

**Options:**

1. Pass client id around everywhere
2. Launch new process per host
3. ?

Is there a better way or have I made a mistake in my assumptions?

If the process per client approach is the better way I am wondering if there is an existing solution to manage this? Ive looked at [http proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), [micro cluster](https://github.com/zeit/micro-cluster) etc but none seem to provide a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this nice tool https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage

```
// Micro handler
const { createNamespace } = require('continuation-local-storage')
let namespace = createNamespace('foo')

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const clientId = // some header thing or host


 namespace.run(function() {
  namespace.set('clientId', clientId)
    someCode()
  })
})


// Some other file
const { getNamespace } = require('continuation-local-storage')

const someCode = () => {
  const namespace = getNamespace('foo')
  console.log(namespace.get('clientId'))
}
```